# image tag and the_post_thumbnail, where?

Tags: wordpress

`the_post_thumbnail()` function is creating an image tag - where does this code located in? Can't find it for some reason (it's not on `post-thumbnail-template.php` and not on `media.php`).

Comment: Ok, got it! It is on media.php - line 567 ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is in the   post-thumbnail-template.php  in wp-includes folder on root  line number  45

```
function the_post_thumbnail( $size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = '' ) {
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $size, $attr );
```

}

Comment: True the code is right ... but I am looking for the <img> output code. Where is the code that actually echoes the <img> tag itself?

Comment: kindly let me know what you want the  path of image or other thing  path can be get by other option  without searching in fils

Comment: try to use this one to get the  image url in your code if post have feature image then it will display  the  url  you can pass this in  img  tag according  to your requirment  $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );    <img src="$url">

Comment: No, that is not what I am after. I will try to explain better:

An <img> tag is being created via the get_the_post_thumbnail() function. I am looking for that little piece of source code that actually echoes the <img> tag.

Comment: Its in media.php  in wp-includes folder   on line number  567

Answer (score 0):

See here at codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail, the_post_thumbnail() is located in wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php.

Comment: bodi0 - I know ;-) Been there and wrote about it ... it's not there.